# Hausdorff dimension of the boundary of an open set in the Euclidean space - lower bound

Tags: gn.general-topology

I consider a bounded open set $A$ in ${\mathbb R}^d$. Is the Hausdorff dimension of the boundary of $A$ at least $d-1$ ? I thought I would have found a result on this problem in any textbook about Hausdorff dimension but I failed. As you may guess I have never work with Hausdorff dimension.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a compact set $C$ separates a connected space $X$ of dimension $d$ (with some homogeneity properties, for example, an euclidean space) in two connected components, then it must have topological dimension at least $d-1$ (see for example the book by Hurewicz and Wallman on topological dimension, Theorem IV.4). In general, [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) exceeds (or is equal to) topological dimension (see chapter VII.2 of the book by Hurewicz-Wallman mentioned above).

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language. I shall correct it.

Comment: By definition (in Hurewicz and Wallman, if I remember correctly), the topological dimension of separable metric space $A$ is the dimension of the boundary (frontier) of $A$ plus one.  Since an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ has dimension $d$, you are done.  But if you start with the definition of topological dimension as Lebesgue's covering dimension, then you might use the theorem above.

Comment: rbell: Actually that is usually called the "inductive dimension".

Answer (score 22):

Here is a simple proof for the Hausdorff dimension. Consider the orthogonal projection to $\mathbb R^{d-1}$. Since $A$ is bounded, the projection of the boundary contains the projection of $A$. The latter is open in $\mathbb R^{d-1}$ and hence has Hausdorff dimension $d-1$. On the other hand, the projection map does not increase Hausdorff dimension since it does not increase distances.

Comment: That's great ! This is really simple. Thank you !